# GetDateTimeFormats meaning of each array position

Tags: c#, .net

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01cf75zk(v=vs.110).aspx GetDateTimeFormats('D') returns an array of four elements, being different versions of the long format date. Is there a description, enum or suchlike indicating the meaning of each of the four array elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of elements in the returned array depends on the current culture. For example, on a German machine, there are only three elements. The elements are those you can choose from in the Windows Date and Time Formatting Settings.

Comment: Ah! Then maybe I should rephrase my question. The real requirement is: output a date in human-friendly format, such that the program will work on any Windows machine, and given that the programmer doesn't have access to machines with all the various culture settings to debug on. What is the recommended way to do that?

Comment: I don't understand. `.ToString("D")` will take care of it, won't it?